# What is the best way to send a list of arguments to a function within a class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have a class called Dataset. Now within this dataset there is a function which has been defined to read a csv. Now some of those files comes with different encodings and delimiters etc., So I need to pass a filepath, encodings and delimiter to that function. What is the best way to do this? In future there may be need for few more of these arguments.

```
class Dataset:
     def __init__(self,path):
        self.__fielpath=path
        .......
     def read(self):
        data=pd.read_csv(self.__filepath)
```

For `pd.read_csv()` need to send arguments what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your code doesn’t have all those additional things your question implies. Are they stored as separate attributes, as tuple, as ...? Are they passed to read directly? Also, argument passing is a pretty basic python functionality. What have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter that you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `**kwargs` to pass keyword arguments inside the function

```
class Dataset:
     def __init__(self,path):
        self.__fielpath=path
        .......
     def read(self, **kwargs):
        data=pd.read_csv(self.__filepath, **kwargs)


d = Dataset(path="some_path")
data = d.read(columns=["a","b","c"], skiprows=3)
```